# afreechart Android eclipse esample

Tags: android, eclipse, charts

I am trying to use AFreeChart to display a chart in my activity, I have checked so many documentation throw internet but I do not find any full example, I mean how to build a chart and to show it after in my Layout, I need to show it whining an GUI (same thing like an image in my GUI), y am using eclipse (android 4.2) for it.

Does anyone know how to use AfreeChart in android? Thanks

Comment: Use appropriate tags (android) and rewrite your question, because it will be closed if it remains like it is now.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, since this is an older post I am not sure if you were able to find an answer for this question. This is what needs to be done to display a afree chart in your activity.

1. Create a custom view extending ImageView,  something like blelow

   ```
   public class ChartView extends ImageView
   {
       private Bitmap              bitmap;
       private RectShape           rectArea;
       private Canvas              canvas;
       private AFreeChart          chart;

       public ChartView( Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet )
       {
           super(context, attributeSet);
       }

       public ChartView( Context context )
       {
           super(context);
           intChart();
       }

       private void intChart()
       {
           //Setting different width and height based on the orientation.
           if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
           {
               bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
               rectArea = new RectShape(0.0, 0.0, 400, 200);
           }
           else
           {
               bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
               rectArea = new RectShape(0.0, 0.0, 200, 200);
           }
       }

       public void drawChart( AFreeChart chart )
       {
           canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
           this.chart = chart;             
           this.chart.draw(canvas, rectArea);
           setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
       {
           super.onDraw(canvas);               
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an activity, as shown below and you all set to go. I assume that you have already created your AFreeChart object to be passed to the view.

   ```
       public class ChartActivity extends Activity
       {
           @Override
           protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
           {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.chart);

               ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

               ChartView chartView = new ChartView(this);

               chartView.drawChart(ChartFactory.createChart()/*Returns AFreechart object*/);       

               viewGroup.addView(chartView);

           }
       }
   ```
3. chart.xml

   ```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical" >

           </LinearLayout>
   ```

Hope this helps